# How to store templated object<T> in a vector without knowing type T?

Tags: c++, templates

I am having trouble solving this problem. So say I have a class A with a member that is a vector of objects `SomeClass<T>`. And there is a templated method `add_some_class_to_vector<T>` that adds a new instance of `SomeClass<T>` to the vector.

So the flow I currently have is:

1. make new instance of A.
2. call `add_some_class_to_vector<T>`

The problem is, the vector does not know what typename T is.

Without templating the class definition A, how can I tell the member vector what typename it will use?

```
class A {
public:
  //fields
  std::vector<SomeClass<T>> vector_of_some_class; // doesn't know what T is

  //methods
  template<typename T>
  void add_some_class_to_vector();
    vector_of_some_class.push_back(SomeClass<T>());
};

int main() {

  A a()
  a.add_some_class_to_vector<int>();

}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the vector after that. If `SomeClass` is under your control, then you could add a non-template base (that's always the same regardless of the template arguments), then you can store `std::unique_ptr<Base>` in the vector. If not, you could store `std::any`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks a lot for providing two solutions! That about answers my question

Comment: But the thing with `Base` would only work if the child class does not introduce new fields. Otherwise the class would be sliced...

Comment: How do you plan to use the vector? as you need some kind of type erasure actually.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am trying to use the vector to store instances of SomeClass then retrieve them back later. I actually just ran into an issue making a method to return an item from the vector. Using the base class suggestion, the method's return type must be the base class which isn't exactly what I want, because I want to return SomeClass<T> and not BaseSomeClass

Comment: @seanngpack Are you wanting to add multiple `SomeClass<T>` objects of different `T``s to the `vector` at the same time?  If so, that will simply not work unless they all derive from a common base class. A `vector` can only hold 1 type at a time. Otherwise, if they are all going to be the same `T` then just apply the template to `A` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the ```T```'s are homogenous, my main stipulation was to keep ```A``` untemplated, but that is seeming more unlikely because of all this trouble I'm having trying to enforce that condition haha